# How to display rss feed results in a jquery list

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, rss

I would like to display my blog post results as a jQuery mobile lists. For now all the titles, date, author and snippets are appearing line by line and also I would like to be able to click on each posts and view the contents directly as a mobile format. This is my code:

```
$(document).ready((function(){
     url = 'http://hopexxx.com/category/daily-devotion/feed/';
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: document.location.protocol + '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=1000&callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent(url),
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function(){
            alert('Unable to load feed, Incorrect path or invalid feed');
        },
        success: function(xml){
            postlist = xml.responseData.feed.entries;
            //console.log(postlist);
            var data='<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true">';
            $.each(postlist, function(idx, data) {
                $('#postlist').append('<div class="entry">' + data.title + '</div>');
                $('#postlist').append('<div class="entry">' + data.author + '</div>');
                $('#postlist').append('<div class="entry">' + data.publishedDate + '</div>');
                $('#postlist').append('<div class="entry">' + data.contentSnippet + '</div>');
                console.log(data);
            '</ul>';
            });
        }
    });
}));
```

html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

    <script src="css/style.css"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="blog" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header" class="sys_hd" data-position="fixed" data-id="sys_header" >
        <h1>Sysads Posts</h1>
        </div><!-- header -->
        <div data-theme="c" data-role="content" id="postlist"> </div><!-- content -->
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-id="sys_footer" >
                    <div data-role="navbar" >
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#blog" class="sys_ft">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#blog" class="sys_ft">Disclaimer</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- navbar --> 
        </div><!-- footer --> 
    </div><!-- page -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    url = 'http://hopexxx.com/category/daily-devotion/feed/';
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: document.location.protocol + '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=1000&callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent(url),
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function(){
            alert('Unable to load feed, Incorrect path or invalid feed');
        },
        success: function(xml){
            var postlist = xml.responseData.feed.entries;
            var html = '<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true">';
            $.each(postlist, function(idx, data) {
                html += '<li>';
                html += '<a href="#">';
                html += '<div class="entry">' + data.title + '</div>';
                html += '<div class="entry">' + data.author + '</div>';
                html += '<div class="entry">' + data.publishedDate + '</div>';
                html += '<div class="entry">' + data.contentSnippet + '</div>';
                html += '</a>';
                html += '</li>';
            });
            html += '</ul>';
            $("#postlist").append(html);
            $("#postlist ul[data-role=listview]").listview();
        });
    });
});
```

All I've done is wrap the posts in individual list items, and also in a link tag.  I don't know what the url for the link is called (what property it is in the returned data), so I've left that as a `#` for you to fill in.

**[Here's a working example...](http://jsfiddle.net/4BkNr/)**

Comment: thanks Archer for your swift response. I have tried your option but it still does not display the result with the line divider. With the refresh option, I am getting: Error: cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'

Comment: Okay - I've removed the refresh and just left it as an initialisation call.  Try that :)

Comment: The display still not formatted in jquery like listview. I have added my html code also

Comment: That's fixed now.  I should have been running the listview initialisation on the UL we just added, not the container :)

Comment: that works. I just need to figure out how I can enable the links so each post displays just the post content and not the whole site. Can you help on that or guide me?

Comment: That's doable, as long as the links point to the same domain and the contents are in a specific element that can be targeted using a css selector.  The jQuery `load()` method allows you to specify an element selector and just loads the contents of that selector from a given url.  [Look here for the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/) and see the section "loading page fragments".

Comment: Thanks for the documentation. Will read through it and practice

Comment: If you get stuck with that, it would be best to start a new question and show the two bits of code above, and the relevant part of the page with the contents you want to load.