# jQuery each() adds all items from feed to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, rss

I am trying to fetch items from an rss feed and put each one in a different div. This is my code:

```
$.ajax({
  url      : document.location.protocol + '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=10&callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent('FEED URL'),
  dataType : 'json',
  success  : function (data) {
    if (data.responseData.feed && data.responseData.feed.entries) {
      $.each(data.responseData.feed.entries, function (i, e) {
        $('<div class="inner"></div>').appendTo('#feed');   
        $(".inner").attr('data-role','collapsible');
        $(".inner").append("<h2>"+e.title+"</h2>");
        $(".inner").append("<p>"+e.content+"</p>");
        $(".inner").collapsible();
        //console.log("------------------------");
        //console.log("title      : " + e.title);
        //console.log("author     : " + e.author);
        //console.log("description: " + e.content);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

The problem is that it also adds every item in the feed to the div before creating the next. The output is like this:

---Collapsible Div with 1st item
------2nd item
------3nd item
------4nd item
---Collapsible Div with 2nd item
------3nd item
------4nd item
---Collapsible Div with 3rd item
------4nd item

Comment: `var $inner = $('<div class="inner"></div>').appendTo('#feed');
$inner.attr('data-role', 'collapsible');
$inner.append("<h2>" + e.title + "</h2>");
$inner.append("<p>" + e.content + "</p>");
$inner.collapsible();`

Comment: My be DUPLICATE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18978470/how-to-display-rss-feed-results-in-a-jquery-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(".inner")` searches for **all** elements with the class `inner` that are currently in the document, so `$(".inner").append("some HTML")` appends it to **all** of them.

If you want to work just with the one for that iteration, save it to a variable, and then use that variable:

```
var inner = $('<div class="inner"></div>').appendTo('#feed');   
inner.attr('data-role','collapsible');
// ...and so on...
```

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is the selector `.inner` if returns all the elements of this class including the ones you just added. change `$(".inner")` to `$(".inner:last-child")`

Comment: And if there are **other** elements on the page with that class which just happen to be the last child in their parent? (And it's pretty silly to constantly re-query the DOM for an element you already have handy.)

Comment: granted you can come up with situations that would require another selector, but that can logically be avoided by the OP if he is familiar with the structure of the code he is writing. I do agree that your answer has better resource efficiency, but rather don't appreciate the `silly` part of your statement

Comment: "Silly" is a *very* mild form of criticism, no offense meant.

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest to take a look at the console output of the return you are doing the each over.  If you have Chrome or Firefox open the console.  In your code you should put:

```
$.ajax({
  url      : document.location.protocol + '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=10&callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent('FEED URL'),
  dataType : 'json',
  success  : function (data) {
    if (data.responseData.feed && data.responseData.feed.entries) {

      //PRINT THE CONTENT
      console.log(data.responseData.feed.entries)


      $.each(data.responseData.feed.entries, function (i, e) {
        $('<div class="inner"></div>').appendTo('#feed');   
        $(".inner").attr('data-role','collapsible');
        $(".inner").append("<h2>"+e.title+"</h2>");
        $(".inner").append("<p>"+e.content+"</p>");
        $(".inner").collapsible();
        //console.log("------------------------");
        //console.log("title      : " + e.title);
        //console.log("author     : " + e.author);
        //console.log("description: " + e.content);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

My guess is that the structure of the return is not exactly what you think it is.

Thanks,
-Kyle